# How can I make this custom menu work?

Tags: jquery, menus, css, sub-menu

Can someone share with me the easiest way to convert this to work with wordpress’s 3.0 built in menu support. So far I have the topnav menu working correctly, but I’m having a hard time getting the subnav  to show. How would you make this code work with a default install of wordpress? I assumed that after adding 
`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'depth' => 0,'menu_class' => 'topnav', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>`

and changing subnav to sub-menu in the js and css. That everything would work. What am I doing wrong?

I’m using jquery 1.6.1
This is the original code from a static html page.
JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>"); //Only shows drop down trigger when js is enabled (Adds empty span tag after ul.subnav*)  

    $("ul.topnav li span").click(function() { //When trigger is clicked...  

        //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)  
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click  

        $(this).parent().hover(function() {  
        }, function(){  
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up  
        });  

        //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)  
        }).hover(function() {  
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"  
        }, function(){  //On Hover Out  
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"  
    });  

});
```

CSS

```
ul.topnav {  
  list-style: none;  
  padding: 0px 0px;  
  margin: -12px -11px 0;  
  float: left;  
  width: 922px;  
  background: #222;  
  font-size: 1.2em;  
  background: url(../images/topnav_bg.gif) repeat-x;  

}  
ul.topnav li {  
    float: left;  
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0 15px 0px 5px;  
    position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base for sub navigation--*/  
}  
ul.topnav li a{  
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 10px;  
    color: #fff;  
    display: block;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    float: left;  
}  
ul.topnav li a:hover{  
    background: url(../images/topnav_hover.gif) no-repeat center top;  
}  
ul.topnav li span { /*--Drop down trigger styles--*/  
    width: 17px;  
    height: 35px;  
    float: left;  
    background: url(../images/subnav_btn1.gif) no-repeat center top;  
}  
ul.topnav li span.subhover {background-position: center bottombottom; cursor: pointer;} /*--Hover effect for trigger--*/  
ul.topnav li ul.subnav {  
    list-style: none;  
    position: absolute; /*--Important - Keeps subnav from affecting main navigation flow--*/  
    left: 0; top: 35px;  
    background: #333;  
    margin: 0; padding: 0;  
    display: none;  
    float: left;  
    width: 195px;  
    border: 1px solid #111; 
    z-index:500; 
}  
ul.topnav li ul.subnav li{  
    margin: 0; padding: 0;  
    border-top: 1px solid #252525; /*--Create bevel effect--*/  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444; /*--Create bevel effect--*/  
    clear: both;  
    width: 195px;  
}  
html ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a {  
    float: left;  
    width: 170px;  
    background: #333 url(../images/dropdown_linkbg.gif) no-repeat 10px center;  
    padding-left: 25px;  
    font-size: 13px;

}  
html ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a:hover { /*--Hover effect for subnav links--*/  
    background: #222 url(../images/dropdown_linkbg.gif) no-repeat 10px center;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the appropriate `theme_location`.

Assuming you've defined multiple nav menu locations using [`register_nav_menus()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus) in functions.php:

```
<?php
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary-menu' => 'Primary Menu',
    'secondary-menu' => 'Secondary Menu'
) );
?>
```

Then you call [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) using the appropriate `theme_location` as defined above, along with any other relevant arguments, e.g.:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
    'menu_class' => 'topnav'
) );

wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu',
    'menu_class' => 'subnav'
) );
?>
```

Also, note that some of your arguments, such as `menu_order`, are not valid arguments for `wp_nav_menu()`. [Here are the defaults](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Default_Usage):

```
<?php $defaults = array(
  'theme_location'  => ,
  'menu'            => , 
  'container'       => 'div', 
  'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container', 
  'container_id'    => ,
  'menu_class'      => 'menu', 
  'menu_id'         => ,
  'echo'            => true,
  'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
  'before'          => ,
  'after'           => ,
  'link_before'     => ,
  'link_after'      => ,
  'items_wrap'      => '<ul id=\"%1$s\" class=\"%2$s\">%3$s</ul>',
  'depth'           => 0,
  'walker'          => );
?>
```

Comment: I have only one menu registered. It has 4 top-top level pages with a few child pages. When I remove the ul.topnav li ul.subnav{} rule I can see the child pages.

It seems like the empty <span> tag isn't being created.

Comment: Okay, let's try this a different way: *what is the markup you want to end up with*?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. This is the menu I'm using.

http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html